# Android - Eclipse will not launch debug application

Tags: android, eclipse

Working off a completely functional code-base I created a copy to develop a separate application.

While attempting to debug on android via Eclipse I see:

```
[2013-09-17 01:29:04 - TarotAdvanced-Android] Android Launch!
[2013-09-17 01:29:04 - TarotAdvanced-Android] adb is running normally.
[2013-09-17 01:29:04 - TarotAdvanced-Android] No Launcher activity found!
[2013-09-17 01:29:04 - TarotAdvanced-Android] The launch will only sync the application      package on the device!
[2013-09-17 01:29:04 - TarotAdvanced-Android] Performing sync
[2013-09-17 01:29:13 - TarotAdvanced-Android] Uploading TarotAdvanced-Android.apk onto device '015d16897a540607'
[2013-09-17 01:29:21 - TarotAdvanced-Android] Installing TarotAdvanced-Android.apk...
[2013-09-17 01:29:24 - TarotAdvanced-Android] Success!
[2013-09-17 01:29:24 - TarotAdvanced-Android] \TarotAdvanced-Android\bin\TarotAdvanced-Android.apk installed on device
[2013-09-17 01:29:24 - TarotAdvanced-Android] Done!
```

And then nothing happens. I've already disabled automatic debug target selection so that it prompts me for the device. Before the above occurs I'm prompted for my target device. It doesn't matter what device I use. The end result is the same, messages of installation but the application (apk) is no where to be found on the device. Whereas with the source of the copy I can always find the apk the debugger copied over.

If I manually copy over the APK and install it on the device then it works fine. Eclipse is glitching out. How do I work around this?

Comment: post your Manifest here

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `Manifest`

```
<activity  android:name="YourPackage.ActivityName"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
               <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem recently and this did the trick for me.

From Eclipse->Run->Debug Configuration->right-click on the Android application->Delete.
After which, go back to Run->Debug As->Android Application

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score -1):

Do you have opened more number of Eclipse instances? if so some times debug doesn't start. Close the other Eclipse instances and try the debug.